# Wordpress nonce check always false

Tags: ajax, wordpress, nonce

I'm having problems with a basic nonce validation via an ajax request.

Those are my script loader and css loader functions:
(in gallery.php)

```
function gallery_js_loader()
{
    if (!is_admin()) return;
    // async flash uploader
    wp_enqueue_script('swfobject', THEMEURL . "/lib/uploadify/swfobject.js", array(), false, true);
    wp_enqueue_script('uploadify', THEMEURL . "/lib/uploadify/jquery.uploadify.v2.1.4.min.js", array('jquery'), false, true);
    wp_enqueue_script('gallery_admin_scripts', THEMEURL . "/inc/galleries/gallery_admin_scripts.js", array(), false, true);
    wp_localize_script('gallery_admin_scripts', 'param',
                   array(
                        'basename' => GALLERYPOST,
                        'baselocation' => THEMEURL,
                        'nonce' => wp_create_nonce('file-upload-nonce'),
                        'thumb_width' => intval(get_option('thumbnail_size_w')),
                        'thumb_height' => intval(get_option('thumbnail_size_h'))
                   ));
// main styles


}

function gallery_css_loader()
{
    wp_enqueue_style('uploadify_styles', THEMEURL . "/lib/uploadify/uploadify.css");
    wp_enqueue_style('gallery_admin_styles', THEMEURL . "/inc/galleries/gallery_admin_styles.css");
}

 add_action('admin_print_scripts-post.php', 'gallery_js_loader');
 add_action('admin_print_scripts-post-new.php', 'gallery_js_loader');
 add_action('admin_print_styles-post.php', 'gallery_css_loader');
 add_action('admin_print_styles-post-new.php', 'gallery_css_loader');


 function gallery_upload_image()
 {
     $nonce = $_POST["nonce"];

     if (is_admin() && !empty($_FILES) /*&& wp_verify_nonce($nonce, 'file-upload-nonce')*/) {
         require_once(ABSPATH . 'wp-admin/includes/image.php');

         $tempFile = $_FILES['Filedata']['tmp_name'];
         //        $targetPath = $_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'] . $_REQUEST['folder'] . '/';
         $targetDir = wp_upload_dir(date('Y'));
         $targetFile = $targetDir['path'] . '/' . $_FILES['Filedata']['name'];
         $targetFile = str_replace(" ", "", $targetFile);

         move_uploaded_file($tempFile, $targetFile);

         $wp_filetype = wp_check_filetype(basename($targetFile), null);

         $attachment = array(
             'post_mime_type' => $wp_filetype['type'],
             'post_title' => preg_replace('/\.[^.]+$/', '', basename($targetFile)),
             'post_content' => '',
             'post_status' => 'inherit'
         );
         $result['attachmet_id'] = $attach_id = wp_insert_attachment($attachment, $targetFile);
         $result['recieved_nonce'] = $nonce;

         $attach_data = wp_generate_attachment_metadata($attach_id, $targetFile);
         wp_update_attachment_metadata($attach_id, $attach_data);

         $result['success'] = true;
     } else {
         $result['success'] = false;
         $result['recieved_nounce'] = $nonce;
         $result['error'] = array(
             'message' => 'No files or you are not admin ' . $nonce,
             'code' => 'E01'
         );
     }

     echo json_encode($result);
     exit;
 }

 add_action('wp_ajax_do_upload', 'gallery_upload_image');
```

In my javascrtip file:
(in gallery.js)

```
console.debug("Nonce received ",param.nonce); //c4817b947a
```

My ajax call will access a do_upload action from php. This one will append the received nonce field to the response... 
(back in gallery.php)

```
function gallery_upload_image()
{
    $nonce = $_POST["nonce"];

    if ( wp_verify_nonce($nonce, 'file-upload-nonce')) {
        /* some logic here, nothing to do with nonce */
        $result['success'] = true;
        $result['debugNonce'] = $nonce;
    } // end validation
    else {
       //invalid nonce
       $result['success'] = false;
       $result['debugNonce'] = $nonce;         
    }
}
```

The received result looks like this:
    c4817b947a {"success":false,"debugNonce":"c4817b947a"}

The first c4817b947a is because of the echo from the nonce generation function. It does not influence the way the validation happens.

My conclusion is that wp_verify_nonce always fails.

I am using wp 3.2.1 on localhost, fresh install, no plugins.

Comment: I am having the same issue since playing with set_transient. How would I get rid of that?

Comment: I've run into the same issue. I noticed that when I'm not logged in (opening the website in incognito mode) the verification works. I've googled this in any ways possible and spent days trying to solve the issue with no success. check_ajax_referer also fails. I'm also running a fresh install, tried both locally and on an online server. But it can't be that it just doesn't work all these years... Have you found the solution?

Answer (score 2):

I've just ran into a [similar issue](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/241854/wp-verify-nonce-always-returns-false-when-logged-in-as-admin/241958#241958) and it turned out that all I had to do is to re-log as admin. I think it should also work in your case, because everything else in the provided code seems to be fine.

I guess it has something to do with how sessions are handled in Wordpress.

Answer (score 0):

I do an almost identical interchange without problems.
This is in a plugin (class), but that shouldn't matter.

PHP - initialize the javascript :

```
add_action( 'wp_print_scripts', array( &$this, 'enqueue_script') );
```

PHP - `function enqueue_script`:

```
wp_localize_script( 'B99-Portfolio', 'ajax', array(  'ajaxurl'       => admin_url( 'admin-ajax.php' ),
                                                     'imgurl'        => content_url().'/uploads/portfolio-content/',
                                                     'requestNonce'  => wp_create_nonce('b99-request-nonce')) );
```

JS - initiate the ajax request:

```
$.ajax({
        type    : 'POST',
        cache   : false,
        url     : ajax.ajaxurl,
        data    : {
            action          : 'b99_ajax_request_items',
            requestNonce    : ajax.requestNonce             
        },
        dataType: 'json',
        error   : function(jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown) {alert(jqXHR+" "+textStatus+" "+errorThrown);},
        success : function( response ) {recieveAjax( response );}
        });
```

PHP - recieve and handle the request ( `function b99_ajax_request_items`):

```
$nonce = $_POST['requestNonce'];
        if ( ! wp_verify_nonce( $nonce, 'b99-request-nonce' ) ){
            die ( 'security fail'.$nonce);
        }
```

Make sure that you have enqueued the script prior to localizing it.

I'm using current versions of both jquery and wordpress and this works seamlessly on a local install of XAMPP. It looks pretty similar to your interchange, but maybe this is something to compare against.

Comment: Thanks for your response. I updated the code to include the full function that loads js and css. My script is enqueued before localized. The nonce is received correctly, but fails to validate...

Comment: What action are you adding gallery_assets_loader() to? I know there are at least three valid insertion points, I use wp_print_scripts. Also, what does your ajax call look like? you mention do_upload on the php side, but you are showing gallery_upload_image(). What does your complete interchange look like?

Comment: I'm sorry for the late replay, and I appreciate your effort. I updated the code. Please take a look. :)